# Using a variable as array index

Tags: arrays, smarty

I have a smarty variable which stores an associative array. Is there a way to combine a string and another smarty variable to create the index?

Example: The array element I want to print is `$foo['index1']` and the variable `$count = 1`. I tried to print the value using `$foo.index$count` but that results in a smarty syntax error (unrecognized tag).

Answer (score 1):

If you have something like this in PHP:

```
$foo['index1'] = 'aaa';
$smarty->assign('foo', $foo);
$smarty->assign('count', 1);
```

Then you should do in smarty:

```
{assign var = "idx" value = "index"|cat:$count}
{$foo[$idx]}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Like this you can get the index count in foreach:**

```
{foreach from=$value item=foo key=k name=myloop}                                
{assign var=op value=$smarty.foreach.myloop.index}
index count:{$op}
{/foreach}
```